# Use different viewport on tablet landscape

Tags: css, viewport, tablet

I use the following viewport to show all content on my tablet, my site is only 980px width.
When I use this all content on the site is visible and I like this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1600" />
```

But for portrait it needs to be **width=1000**.
Is there any way we can play with orientation:landscape?
I'm looking for a js solution.

*I tried using css solution but my fullscreen background slider don't work correct then (not fullscreen). So if someone knows how to change the meta content width when being on tablet landscape please let me know.*

Tried some solution without luck, I think I'm close thow:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=1000">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (screen.width > 1000) {
            document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=1600");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When checking genereated source it changes correct. Why doesn't it work on my ipad? Tried with and without document ready. Do I need a other approice?

Comment: ok so I need to add portrait or landscape in this: if (screen.width.. That needs to be if screensize.portrait or something

Answer (score 1):

Working without static values for the viewport width would be even better. So you won't have problems if your layout have to fit on other devices with different resolutions. With the content tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Your layout-width is fixed to the device maximum. And it fits whether you're in portrait or in landscape mode.

Comment: no that won't work, same as removing the meta viewport tag. I need to "zoom" on landscape so all content of the page is visible. (the site isn't responsive, no need for that!). with width=1600 this works.

Comment: I know this could be done with CSS but I'm looking for a other solution, my fullscreen background slider breaks apart... with adding viewport width its perfect but not for portrait.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work :D

```
<style>
    @media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
        @-ms-viewport{
            width:1600px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
        @-ms-viewport{
            width:1000px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background image slider was not fullscreen and is fixed by this css.

```
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    html{width: 1600px;}
    #maximage, #maximage .mc-image{width:100%!important; height:100%!important;}
}
```